# ComboBox with button in Delphi

Tags: delphi, button, combobox

In Delphi, I have a ComboBox, and I would like to open a web link when the first item is selected, and an other if the second is selected.

Currently, I am using:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,
           'open',
           'link',
           nil,
           nil,
           SW_SHOW);
```

I want that in combobox would be like: 
Open Gaming site 
Open Server site 
And then selected gaming site opens site1.com, then server site opens site2.com

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the combo box contains the URL then you simply do this:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(ComboBox1.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

There's no need to pass a verb. Pass nil and the default verb is used. In fact sometimes you'll encounter a browser that fails to register an action to the open verb.

If you've stripped off the protocol for the link text that you display in the combo, you should add it back:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar('http://'+ComboBox1.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

---

Judging from the comments what you actually want is a one to one map between a URL and a friendly name. Put them both in a record:

```
type
  TSiteInfo = record
    URL: string;
    FriendlyName: string;
  end;
```

Then create either a list of them, `TList<TSiteInfo>`, or a dynamic array, `TArray<TSiteInfo>` or `array of TSiteInfo`. Then populate the list or array. Then use that structure to populate your combo box with friendly names. When the button is clicked, read the selected index, `ComboBox1.ItemIndex`. And finally, look up the URL using that index.

Yet another option would be to use a dictionary to associate URL and friendly name. Personally, I like the list of `TSiteInfo` better.

Comment: I want that in combobox would be like:
Open Gaming site
Open Server site
And then selected gaming site opens site1.com, then server site opens site2.com

Comment: Why are you telling me this in a comment? Why is that information not in the question. If we are going to do this, you need to put all the information in the question. Anyway, I've updated the answer with an outline of the solution to that.